# Why potassium chromate can be used as indicator in Mohr method?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, titration

Both silver chloride and silver chromate are insoluble, so why is that silver chromate is precipitated before silver chromate? Why wouldn't both red silver chromate and white silver chloride form at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

In the [Mohr method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argentometry#Mohr_method) for argentometry, the $\ce{[Cl-] > [CrO4^{2-}]}$ so $\ce{AgCl v}$ forms first then as $\ce{Cl-}$ is depleted $\ce{[Cl-] \approx [CrO4^{2-}]}$ and $\ce{Ag2CrO4 v}$ will form as well.